# jQuery URL hash input refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

```
        $( "ul#results" ).click(function() {$( this ).slideUp();});
```

I'm using the code in the following tutorial: http://ninetofive.me/blog/build-a-live-search-with-ajax-php-and-mysql Above is my jQuery code targeting the AJAX dropdown.

I'm trying to make the dropdown fade away when the user clicks on a link, without having the page redirect or refresh. I'm also using hashes in the URL (handled server side) for my link. For instance:
                        mysite.com/#selecteddropdowndata

I'm not sure whether the problem is with my URL hashes, jQuery or a combination.

Answer (score 0):

here is a link to a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/6zAYq/2/

If you click on a link (  ) you need to prevent the default click event to go off, and trigger the one you actually want.

html:

```
<ul id="results">
    <li><a href="www.google.com">test123</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.google.com">test123</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.google.com">test123</a></li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$( "a" ).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#results').trigger('click');
});

$('#results').on('click', function(e){
    $( this ).slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable a link when you click on it, use the `preventDefault()` function. Your code shows you're targeting a `<ul>` tag, not a link. Try this instead:

```
$('a.yourlink').click(function(e){
    $("ul#results").slideUp();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```